# ASP.NET RegularExpressionValidator, validate on a non-match?

Tags: asp.net, regex

Is there a way to use the RegularExpressionValidator to validate only when the ValidationExpression does not match?  In particular use a PO BOX regex to validate an address that is **NOT** a PO BOX.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can effectively invert your regular expression using a [negative look-ahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

For example, consider the following regular expression that matches only a string of digits:

```
^\d+$
```

This expression could be inverted as follows:

```
^(?!\d+$).*$
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use NegativeRegularExpressionValidator :)

```
[ToolboxData("<{0}:NegativeRegularExpressionValidator runat=\"server\" ErrorMessage=\"NegativeRegularExpressionValidator\"></{0}:NegativeRegularExpressionValidator>")]
public class NegativeRegularExpressionValidator : RegularExpressionValidator
{
    protected override bool EvaluateIsValid()
    {
        return base.EvaluateIsValid() == false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice, I am going to give it a shot.  ty

Comment: Unfortunately, nothing about client side :(. Thank you for pointing this out. My aim was to give an idea, not more.

Answer (score 1):

Create a regular expression that validates NOT a PO BOX or use custom validator.

Comment: I agree, this would be ideal.  But inverting an existing regex is non trivial?

Comment: It depends on the regexp itself, but as far as I know there is no magic 'not' switch on the whole expression.

Comment: Right, characters can be negated but not the whole expression (as far as i can tell).   In the mean time it's a custom validator.

Answer (score 1):

Mike Chaliy's solution is very good, but it doesn't validate in client-side.

I think you should use a [custom validator control](https://web.archive.org/web/20210608194151/http://aspnet.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/073102-1.aspx) and write a javascript function that validates not a POBox. copy pattern from regular expression validator and use [this site](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html) to write your own client side validation.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution for client side scripting:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="MYiD" />


<asp:CustomValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="MyId" ErrorMessage="Wrong"
    ClientValidationFunction="ClientValidate" />



<asp:Button runat="server" OnClick="OnClick" />

<script language="javascript"> 
function ClientValidate(source, arguments)
{
    var value = arguments.Value;
    var res = value.match('abc');       
    arguments.IsValid = (res == null || res === undefined);
}
</script>
```