# How do I get a RegularExpressionValidator to NOT match a case insensitive, entire string?

Tags: asp.net, regex

Here are my two reg expressions. The first one seems to match my case insensitive string exactly, but the second one has a space and isn't working.

```
^([wW][eE][eE][kK][5][0][0])$


^([wW][eE][eE][kK][/s][5][0][0])$
```

So I have two problems:
1) What do I change so that my first reg expression in my asp RegularExpressionValidator will **not** match my "Week500" case insensitive, entire string? I only want it to fire if this entire string (albeit case insensitive) is matched. Currently this reg expression is doing the opposite of what I need.
2) I also need this same change for my second reg expression in my second asp RegularExpressionValidator. However, it has a space in a specific place in the string "Week 500".

Here are the complete tags for my two RegularExpressionValidators on my asp page:
`<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="revPrevEventNameDup" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtGenerateEventsPreviewEventName" EnableClientScript="true" ErrorMessage="Dup Name" Display="Dynamic" ValidationExpression="^([wW][eE][eE][kK][5][0][0])$" ValidationGroup="GenerateEventsPreviewValidation" />`

`<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="revPrevEventNameDup" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtGenerateEventsPreviewEventName" EnableClientScript="true" ErrorMessage="Dup Label" Display="Dynamic" ValidationExpression="^([wW][eE][eE][kK][5][0][0])$" ValidationGroup="GenerateEventsPreviewValidation" />`

Thank you in advance for your help.

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

I'm new so I can't answer my own question, so it suggested I put the answer here...

Thank you all for the string help!!

You're all GREAT!!

Here: 
[ASP.NET RegularExpressionValidator, validate on a non-match?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/549628/asp-net-regularexpressionvalidator-validate-on-a-non-match)

I found that I had to add:
    ^(?!

to the front and:
    $).*$

to the end to get the validate on a non-match.

So here are my two finial RegularExpressionValidators for my asp page that work GREAT!!

```
ValidationExpression="^(?!([wW][eE][eE][kK]500)$).*$"

ValidationExpression="^(?!([wW][eE][eE][kK] 500)$).*$"
```

THANK YOU!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The white-space matching regular expression is `\s`, not `/s`.

```
^([wW][eE][eE][kK][\s][5][0][0])$
```

If all you need is a space, just type it.

```
^([wW][eE][eE][kK] [5][0][0])$
```

And, if you want to match a single character, just type those too, unless they are special:

```
^([wW][eE][eE][kK] 500)$
```

And in all cases, if `\` is special to your string holder, you may need to escape the escape character, using `\\`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this regex ? `^([wW][eE][eE][kK][\s][5][0][0])$`
I change / to \

Comment: You guys are all GREAT!!

Here 
[stackExchange](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/549628/asp-net-regularexpressionvalidator-validate-on-a-non-match)
I found that I had to add:
    ^(?!
to the front and:
    $).*$
to the end to get the validate on a non-match.

So here are my two finial reg exs that work GREAT!!
    "^(?!([wW][eE][eE][kK]500)$).*$"
    "^(?!([wW][eE][eE][kK] 500)$).*$"

THANK YOU!!!